# Save the value in PyQT and then use this value in another Combo box

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I want to use input variable in Y-Number label for filtering AP Combo box values. But I cannot save the current variable in Y-Number or the other name input variable. I use QLineEdit for find the Y Number because it has auto fill. In filtered part (AP version), valued should came when selected the Y number

```
class Window(QWidget):
        
    def updateyNumber(self):
        
        print(str(self.APComboBox.currentText()))
        
        if self.yNumberComboBox != "":
            for i in range(len(responsesDecoded_GetAllVersionPB)):
                if self.yNumberComboBox.text() == responsesDecoded_GetAllVersionPB[i]['YNumber']:
                        y = responsesDecoded_GetAllVersionPB[i]['Version']
                        All_Ynumbers_Version.append([y])
                else:
                    #♣print("none y combo")
                    if self.yNumberComboBox.text() != None:
                        print("y num came: {0}".format(self.yNumberComboBox.text()))
        versionss = np.unique(All_Ynumbers_Version)
        self.APComboBox.addItems(versionss)
        
        
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        
        # setting window title
        self.setWindowTitle("FastFEM 4.1")
  
        # setting geometry to the window
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 400)
  
        # creating a group box
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox()
  
        info = ["MSD", "Custom", "Qstat", "Test", "Admin"]
        
        # completer
        completeryNum = QCompleter(yNumbers)
        
        # creating combo box to select yNumber
        self.yNumberComboBox = QLineEdit()
        
        self.yNumberComboBox.setCompleter(completeryNum)
        
        #self.yNumberComboBox.currentTextChange.connect(self.updateyNumberComboBox)
        
        # creating combo box to select AP/Ti
        self.APComboBox = QComboBox()  
        
        self.updateyNumber()
        # adding version items to the combo box
        #self.APComboBox.addItems(versionss)
        
        self.APComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.updateyNumber)
        
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        
        # creating combo box to select FastFEM Criteria
        self.FastFEMComboBox = QComboBox()
  
        # adding criteria items to the combo box
        self.FastFEMComboBox.addItems(info)
  
        # creating a line edit
        self.PRVPressure = QLineEdit()
        
        self.NeedForce = QLineEdit()
 
        # calling the method that create the form
        self.createForm()
        
        # creating a vertical layout
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
         
        # adding form group box to the layout
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
                   
        # setting lay out
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        
        
    # get info method called when form is accepted
    def getInfo(self):
  
        # printing the form information
        print("Y-Number           : {0}".format(self.yNumberComboBox.text()))
        print("AP/Ti              : {0}".format(self.APComboBox.currentText()))
        print("FastFEM Criteria   : {0}".format(self.FastFEMComboBox.currentText()))
        print("Prv Pressure (bar) : {0}".format(self.PRVPressure.text()))
        print("Needle Force (N)   : {0}".format(self.NeedForce.text()))
        
        # clear the table
        self.yNumberComboBox.clear()
        self.APComboBox.clear()
        self.FastFEMComboBox.clear()
        self.PRVPressure.clear()
        self.NeedForce.clear()
        
        # closing the window
        #self.close()
 
    # creat form method
    def createForm(self):
  
        # creating a form layout
        layout = QFormLayout()
  
        # adding rows  
        # for yNumber and adding combo box
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Y-Number"), self.yNumberComboBox)
            
        # for APP/Ti and adding combo box
        layout.addRow(QLabel("AP/Ti"), self.APComboBox)
        
        # for FastFEM Criteria adding combo box
        layout.addRow(QLabel("FastFEM Criteria"), self.FastFEMComboBox)
        
        # for PRV Pressure adding input variable
        layout.addRow(QLabel("PRV Pressure (bar)"), self.PRVPressure)
        
        # for Needle Force adding input variable
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Needle Force (N)"), self.NeedForce)
        
        # start fastFEM and cancel buttons
        startButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        startButton.clicked.connect(self.cancelClicked)
        cancelButton = QPushButton("Start FastFEM")
        cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.getInfo)
        
        layout.addRow(startButton, cancelButton)
        
        # setting layout
        
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
        
        return self.yNumberComboBox.text()
        
#def closeEvent(self, event):
#    reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Window Close', 'Are you sure you want to close the window', 
#            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
#    
#    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
#        event.accept()
#        
#    else:
#        event.ignore()
            
    def cancelClicked(self):
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

    def saveClick(self):
        self.APComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.updateyNumberComboBox)
```

[PyQt forms look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngwCW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that way you get what you're looking for.
I shortened the example to make it easier to understand.

Changes:

- You didn't define `yNumbers`, I defined it as the list ['111', '444', '777']
- `yNumberComboBox` using textChanged to connect with `updateyNumberComboBox`
- The `APComboBox` combox change being promoted by `yNumberComboBox` , not itself, so I removed `APComboBox.currentTextChanged`
- For `APComboBox` not to contain duplicate items,
  you can clear before adding items.
  self.APComboBox.clear()
  self.APComboBox.addItems()

  ```
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QComboBox, QLineEdit, QGroupBox, QCompleter
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFormLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
    import numpy as np
    import sys

    class Window(QWidget):

        def __init__(self):
            super(Window, self).__init__()
            self.setWindowTitle("FastFEM 4.1")
            self.setGeometry(400, 800, 250, 150)

            self.responsesDecoded_GetAllVersionPB = [
                {'YNumber':'111', 'Version': 'V1'},
                {'YNumber':'444', 'Version': 'V4'},
                {'YNumber':'777', 'Version': 'V7'}
            ]
            self.All_Ynumbers_Version = []
            layout = QFormLayout()

            yNumbers  = ['111', '444', '777']
            completeryNum = QCompleter( yNumbers )
            self.yNumberComboBox = QLineEdit()        
            self.yNumberComboBox.setCompleter(completeryNum)
            self.yNumberComboBox.textChanged.connect(self.updateyNumber)        
            layout.addRow(QLabel("Y-Number"), self.yNumberComboBox)

            self.APComboBox = QComboBox()  
            layout.addRow(QLabel("AP/Ti"), self.APComboBox)

            self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox()
            self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
            mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()         
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)                   
            self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        def updateyNumber(self):
            yn = self.yNumberComboBox.text()
            if yn:
                for i in range(len(self.responsesDecoded_GetAllVersionPB)):
                    if yn == self.responsesDecoded_GetAllVersionPB[i]['YNumber']:
                        vpb = self.responsesDecoded_GetAllVersionPB[i]['Version']
                        self.All_Ynumbers_Version.append(vpb)
                        self.APComboBox.clear() 
                        self.APComboBox.addItems(np.unique(self.All_Ynumbers_Version))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        App = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(App.exec())
  ```